# Mock implementation of another module not working in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am unit testing (using jest) a function named "getTripDetails" (inside file trip.js) that calls another file "getTrace.js" from different module (which exports a function as shown below).

I want to mock the call of function "getTrace" while testing "getTripDetails" function.

file: trips.js

```
const gpsTrace = require("./gpsTrace");

getTripDetails = async(req, res)=>{
    let gpsTraceRes = await gpsTrace(req.body, req.adToken)
    //more code...
    return {status:200};
}
```

file: getTrace.js

```
module.exports = async(payload, token) =>{
   try {
    //code
   } catch (e) {
     error(e)
     throw new Error(e)
   }
}
```

This is what i tried after reading the docs.

file: test.js

```
let ctrl = require("./trips");

describe("API -- testing", function () {

    it("Trip details", async function () {

        jest.mock('./gpsTrace');
        const gpsTrace = require('./gpsTrace');
        gpsTrace.mockImplementation(() => {});
        gpsTrace();
       
        await  ctrl.getTripDetails({},{});
        expect(response.status).to.eql(200);
    });
});
```

It did not get mocked, instead it was calling the original implementation.

Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close! Here are the updated files with comments describing the changes:

**gpsTrace.js**

Added a `console.log` message. We won't see this in the test if the mock works successfully.

```js
module.exports = async (payload, token) => {
  try {
   //code
   console.log("You won't see me in the Jest test because of the mock implementation")
  } catch (e) {
    error(e)
    throw new Error(e)
  }
}
```

**trips.js**

You needed to export your code to be used in other modules. Seeing as you're calling `ctrl.getTripDetails()` in the test, it makes sense to export your `getTripDetails()` on an object at the bottom of the file.

```js
const gpsTrace = require("./gpsTrace");

const getTripDetails = async (req, res) =>{
  let gpsTraceRes = await gpsTrace(req.body, req.adToken)
  //more code...
  return { status:200 };
}

module.exports = {
  getTripDetails,
}
```

**gpsTrace.test.js**

Make sure to import your modules at the top of the file. Remember that `ctrl.getTripDetails({}, {})` calls `gpsTrace` internally, so no need to call it twice in your test. You also needed to save the response returned from getTripDetails into a variable to be able to compare it: `const response = await ctrl.getTripDetails({}, {});`.

```js
// make sure your require statements go at the top of the module
const gpsTrace = require('./gpsTrace');
let ctrl = require("./trips");

jest.mock('./gpsTrace');
gpsTrace.mockImplementation(() => {});

describe("API -- testing", function () {
  it("Trip details", async function () {
    // ctrl.getTripDeals() calls your gpsTrace function internally, so no need to call it twice
    // gpsTrace(); <-- can be removed
    
    // you needed to save the returned response into a variable to be able to test it.
    const response = await ctrl.getTripDetails({}, {}); 
    
    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
  });
});
```

**Result**
After running the test it now successfully passes. Notice that we DO NOT see the `console.log` message in the `gpsTrace` function, which indicates our mockedImplementation of the function is working in the test script.

[image: Passing Tests]